# Is it possible to use different classifiers in sklearn.ensemble?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I have been learning sklearn.ensemble, for example, 
`clf =AdaBoostClassifier(svm.LinearSVC(),n_estimators=10,max_samples=0.1,)`

My question is whether I can use different classifiers as the `base_estimator`, because `base_estimator` can only accept one `Object`, if I want to use `LogisticRegression()` to continue classifying instances that are misclassified by  `LinearSVC()`, what should I do?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

`AdaBoostClassifier` can only train homogeneous estimators. scikit-learn does not support training heterogeneous ensembles. You might want to have a look at [pyensemble](https://github.com/dclambert/pyensemble).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mean scikit-learn does not support training heterogeneous ensenmbles? I have read the [pyensemble](https://github.com/dclambert/pyensemble). But I am a newbie in this field. Would you please show me some example code?

Comment: Yes I mean "scikit-learn does not support training heterogeneous ensembles" exactly as I have already written. You could also subclass AdaBoostClassifier and override its fit method to do what you want instead.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. As I am a newbie in scikit,  actually I do not know how to override the `fit` method in `AdaBoostClassifier`.could you please show me some sample code that can give me some inspiration?

Comment: Read the source code of the AdaBoostClassifier class.

Comment: Thank you for your instructions. But where can I find the source code of the `AdaBoostClassifier` class ? In scikit, there is no source code but only the usage of `AdaBoostBlassifier`. Could you please show me some source code? I really need your help!

Comment: This is Python, you have all the source where you installed the module, that is, somewhere under your site-packages/sklearn folder. Furthermore, scikit-learn is an open source project hosted on github.com, you can use the search engine their to find the file: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py